# Can't get shrinkwrap to work in project method

Tags: edit-mode

First time using shrinkwrap modifier.
I have created a simple fire extinguisher and I have an image of a label I want to add to the surface.
I can shrinkwrao using nearest surface point but that deforms the label so I considered using the project method but I can't get it to 'shrinkwrap' onto the body of my fire extinguisher.
I have attached my blender file.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label has a rotation on it.

Apply the rotation so that it fits to the X axis choosen in the modifier (or modify the modifier axis, to Z in this case):

[image]

Comment: Thanks lemon. I should have realised that but was following a youtube tutorial which didn't 'do' that.